# How to solve python limited array length

Tags: python, arrays

I am on a 32-bit machine with a 32-bit version of Python.

When I try to make a large array, I get the following error when my array length is `5592406`:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/root/PycharmProjects/stackidiots/main.py", line 3, in <module>
>     dd [x] = x
> IndexError: list assignment index out of range
> ```

Is it Python's limit or I got something wrong with my code?
Here is my code:

```
dd = []
for x in range(5592406):
    dd [x] = x
```

So how to solve this problem? Can it become bigger if I switch to 64-bit?

Comment: *i got something wrong with my code*  is to unspecific. Please paste the full error message in your question.

Comment: *What* error do you get? Show the complete error message, including any stack trace. If the code you've posted is literally what you ran, the error doesn't have anything to do with 32-bitness, Python limits, or the number 5592406; you're trying to assign to list entries that don't exist.

Answer (score 3):

No it is **not** a limit in Python's ability.

Rather, you have made an error in your code.

You'll notice that your error says:

> `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Note the *list assignment* piece. You are trying to assign x to an indice in the list that doesn't exist yet. When you do `dd [x] = x`.

Instead, just append x to the list with [`list.append(value)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
dd = []
for x in range(5592406):
    dd.append(x)
```

Although this works, it is cumbersome and can be more easily done on one line with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
dd = [x for x in range(5592406)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest solution to your problem is:

```
dd = list(range(5592406))
```

This works for Python 2 and 3.

The error message:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Tells you that you try to assign to an index that does not (yet) exist.
This has nothing to do with 32 or 64-bit version of Python.